# "If" statement with "goto" error

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

EDIT: I figured out the issue. My input variable and 'If' variables were different, I forgot to change one of them after I changed it.

So I'm running into issues with my code.

Error;

```
"goto installupdate" was unexpected at this time
```

It all works up to the

```
if %updatech%==Y goto iu
if %updatech%==y goto iu
if %updatech%==N goto noupdate
if %updatech%==n goto noupdate
```

And I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Anyone have any idea what's going wrong in my code?

Code:

REM Check for an update to the installer

```
:updatecheck
bitsadmin.exe /transfer "updatecheck" "http://serverse.playat.ch/overtone/update.txt" "%temp%\overtoneupdate.txt"
set /p versioncompare=<"%temp%\overtoneupdate.txt"
del "%temp%\overtoneupdate.txt"
cls
if %currentbuild% == %versioncompare% goto noupdate
set /p updateyn=New version found! Would you like to update? [Y/N]:
if %updatech%==Y goto iu
if %updatech%==y goto iu
if %updatech%==N goto noupdate
if %updatech%==n goto noupdate
goto updatecheck

:iu
bitsadmin.exe /transfer "update" "http://serverse.playat.ch/overtone/%versioncompare%update.bat" "%cd%\update.bat"
echo %versioncompare%>upvers.txt
update.bat
exit

:noupdate
 cls
 goto install
```

Comment: I've posted the solution (which you've found already from the sounds of it), but I've also added an extra note as you're code will currently break if someone just presses the enter key when you prompt them about the new version.

Comment: `if /?`. Take a look to the `/i` parameter to shorten your code. Also you might be interested in the `choice` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following line of code, you are setting a variable called `updateyn`, but checking a variable called `updatech`.

```
set /p updateyn=New version found! Would you like to update? [Y/N]:
if %updatech%==Y goto iu
```

This is always empty, so it fails, as it boils down to

```
if ==Y goto iu
```

which is not valid syntax.

As well as fixing the variable name, you should also consider the case where the user just presses enter (which will cause the same problem).

You can work around that by putting a known string around the variable

```
    if x%updateyn%x==xYx goto iu
```

for example.

Comment: It's standard practice to use quotes around both the variable name and the value instead of `x`. This way, special characters get preserved.

Comment: Can't quotes cause issues, for example if you have a quoted path?

Comment: Yes, @RB.; but it is also good practice to *not* put the quotes into variable values, but place them at expansion only; e. g.: `set "FILE=.\path\to\file.txt"` sets `FILE` to a value *without* quotes; when using the value, state `"%FILE%"`; so you have the quotes at one place only (at expansion), and you can even easily concatenate paths like `"%FOLDER%\%FILE%"` (imagine the result if both values already contained the quotes)...

Comment: @RB., to avoid trouble with any characters, the only option is [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), because then the value is expanded *after* the command line is parsed where special characters are recognised by the command interpreter...